# In xpath why can I use greater-than symbol > but not less-than <

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, syntax

Using c#3 compiled transforms the following seems to work just fine...

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$valA > $valB">
        <xsl:value-of select="$maxUnder" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$valA &lt; $valC">
        <xsl:value-of select="$maxOver" />
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

However if i dare use a `<` in place of `&lt;` it gives an error...

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$valA > $valB">
        <xsl:value-of select="$maxUnder" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$valA < $valC">
        <xsl:value-of select="$maxOver" />
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

> System.Xml.XmlException: '<',
>   hexadecimal value 0x3C, is an invalid
>   attribute character.

So why is `>` ok and not `<` ?

Comment: FWIW in java it seems that I can use both "like normal"...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because `>` isn't a reserved character in XML, but `<` is.

From [section 2.4 of the XML 1.0 spec (5th edition)](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax):

> The ampersand character (`&`) and the
>   left angle bracket (`<`) must not appear
>   in their literal form, except when
>   used as markup delimiters, or within a
>   comment, a processing instruction, or
>   a CDATA section. If they are needed
>   elsewhere, they must be escaped using
>   either numeric character references or
>   the strings "`&amp;`" and "`&lt;`"
>   respectively. The right angle bracket
>   (`>`) may be represented using the
>   string "`&gt;`", and must, for
>   compatibility, be escaped using either
>   "`&gt;`" or a character reference when
>   it appears in the string "`]]>`" in
>   content, when that string is not
>   marking the end of a CDATA section.

Comment: [The right angle bracket (>) may be represented using the string &gt;, and must, for compatibility, be escaped using either &gt; or a character reference] does this mean that even though I can use it directly I shouldn't? cheers. T

Comment: @runrunraygun: No. In fact I always use and recommend using `>`. This makes your code much more natural and understandable than when using `&gt;`

Comment: Cheers Dimitre, I'm think about instructing all our codes to use > in place of gt; and instead of using lt; invert the statement and use > unless other considerations make that a less natural option.

Comment: Also, you can use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions to eliminate the need for < at all. `$valC > $valA` is logically equivalent, and eliminates the need for escaping the operator. It's a matter of personal choice whether you consider `1 > foo` to be more or less readable than `foo &lt; 1`, however.